# C# SOCKS5 Proxy Implementation doesn't always work on local computer

Tags: c#, proxy, server, socks

**Context**

I made a SOCKS 5 Proxy implementation in C# based on the [RFC 1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) specification as part of a software I'm working on. The proxy server will run locally inside my software (i.e. it's not on a remote server) and it will be used to redirect certain `HTTP` / `HTTPS` connections to a specific IP address.

**How it should work / the reason for a local proxy**

My software is sort of a launcher that launches a `.jar` file. The java program accepts optional parameters that specify a proxy server, and I want to exploit this feature to redirect any `HTTP` or `HTTPS` requests made by the java program to my own servers. This is why the proxy server MUST run on the same computer as the proxy client (the java program).

**My problem**

I am testing this proxy with a simple java program that tries to get a status code from a website through my proxy. For some reason, without modifying any code, approximately 8 times out of 10 the java program throws a SocketException (`java.net.SocketException: Reply from SOCKS server has bad length`), but at other times it works and properly prints out the HTTP response code.

**What I've tried**

If I run the proxy program on a separate computer or on a virtual machine, it always works without any errors (at least hopefully; I ran the java program ~20 times and it didn't throw the exception). This is not a viable solution in my case, because the proxy must run locally, as part of the program I'm working on.

**My Code**

The C# SOCKS implementation is too long for a SO post (~100 lines), so I have uploaded it to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Q1ZjqtD7).

The following is my java test code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 32128));

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://somedomain.com/")
        .openConnection(proxy));
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(false);
    conn.connect();

    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
}
```

**The Question**

Why does the proxy server work if I host it on a separate computer / VM, but fail when I host (and use) it locally? And when it does work locally, what could be the cause of the seemingly random behavior, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the code currently only functions as a transparent proxy, i.e. it doesn't relay connections to other IP addresses yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just revisited this project after a 6 months break, and I have found the solution to this problem. On lines 70-73 the first four bytes of the response are sent separately with `writer.Write(...)`. I solved the problem by replacing those four lines with a single Write call that sends an array (`byte[4]`) containing the four values.